# Fixed Column plugin with JQuery Datatables.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, datatables

Using C# 3.0 data is tranferred to client in the form of table output. Datatable is used to transform it and the plugin used is FixedColumns (latest)

Particulars: First column is a checkbox with state and text bound like: (ASPX code)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company Name">
<ItemTemplate>&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <asp:CheckBox runat="server"  ID="checkboxValid" Checked='<%#Eval("Selected")%>' Text='<%#Eval("CompanyName")%>' />
 </ItemTemplate> 
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Issue: Found that checkbox state is not saved when paging is enabled on the page. When paging is disabled, however there is no issue and the state is getting saved.

All the other checkbox states are getting saved (visually visible) in this case [which are not fixed columns].

When fixedColumn plugin was removed it started working (with paging and without paging).

*Why is this behaviour happening in Datatable v1.9 with the FixedColumns plugin?*

How can I get rid of this?

Similar thread: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6923/need-help-on-maintaining-the-checkbox-state-when-fixed-columns-enabled/p1

PS: I tried to update my code with the hints in the thread, but its not helping the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in : http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/9392/basic-datatable-behaviour-clarification#Item_6